# Power Point Presentation two monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I need to realize a presentation with this approach:

I have a PC connected to two monitors that extend the desktop. My power point presentation must run different contents on each monitor, but each monitor must transition at the same time, like they was only a single presentation. It possible to do this with PowerPoint 2013? I have already seen the external monitor option but it creates something like "screen 1 with relator view and screen 2 with slides view".

Comment: To run two different slide sets on different monitors I would think you would need two instances of powerpoint running.

Comment: Or one Powerpoint Viewer and one PowerPoint, but hey, that won't turn the pages synchronously at all.

Comment: You asked specifically for two monitors with extended desktop, but still a simple solution would be to switch to "duplicate" the screen during the presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerPoint will not do that natively. It can only focus on one presentation at a time.

You may want to give [PowerShow](http://officeone.mvps.org/powershow/powershow.html) a look. It is a plugin for PowerPoint to view them simultaneously. Although it is not free, it does offer what you are looking for.

> Microsoft PowerPoint enables you to start slide shows on different
> monitors. By the design of PowerPoint, only one show can be active at
> any time. PowerShow works around this limitation to enable you to view
> all the shows simultaneously.
>
> The Synchronous Shows feature of PowerShow enables slide shows to run
> on multiple monitors synchronized with each other.

[image]